# Regex match an optional number of digits

Tags: regex

I have a list that could look sort of like

```
("!Goal 27' Edward Nketiah"),
("!Goal 33' 46' Pierre Emerick-Aubameyang"),
("!Sub Nicolas Pepe"),
("Jordan Pickford"),
```

and I'm looking to match either `!Sub` or `!Goal 33' 46'` or `!Goal 27'`

Right now I'm using the regex `(!\w+\s)` which will match `!Goal` and `!Sub`, but I want to be able to get the timestamps too. Is there an easy way to do that? There is no limit on the number of timestamps there could be.

Comment: `(!\w+(?:\s\d+')*)` - you didn't mention if you want to capture each piece individually, your regex engine, or how many timestamps are possible (I'm assuming 0 or more - appears to be football/soccer related)

Comment: Don't the subs have timestamps?

Comment: That looks perfect, yes football, 0 or more is a safe bet. Not sure why I was struggling so much with the optional arguments.

Comment: Your regex suggests you want to match any word preceded by an exclamation mark. Is that true, or is it only `"!Goal"` and `"!Sub"` you wish to match, and if so, must `"!Goal"` always be followed by one or more timestamps and `"!Sub"` never followed by a timestamp?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The regex in my post matches `!Goal` or `!Sub`, which I use elsewhere. In this specific example I'm looking for just the goal info, so I can change the regex to be `!Goal\s`

Comment: The regular expressions given in all the answers match ’ `"!Cat 27', Edward”`. If you are happy with that, that’s fine, but if you want to match only one of two specific words in place of `"Cat"` (e.g., `"Goal"` or `"Sub"`), it's not, as you cannot simply substitute a literal for `\w` in the regular expression. If you will only be looking for one specific word at a time it would be clearer to have had `"!Goal"` in your regex and no `"!Sub"` example, as it's obvious that `"Goal"` could be replaced with a different word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use the following regex to accomplish this:

```
(!\w+(?:\s\d+')*)
```

Explanation:

- `(!\w+(?:\s\d+')*)` capture the following

  - `!` matches this character literally
  - `\w+` matches one or more word characters
  - `(?:\s\d+')*` match the following non-capture group zero or more times

    - `\s` match a whitespace character
    - `\d+` matches one or more digits
    - `'` match this character literally

Additionally, the first capture group isn't necessary - you can remove it to simply match:

```
!\w+(?:\s\d+')*
```

If you need each timestamp, you can use `!\w+(\s\d+')*` and split capture group 1 on the space character.

Comment: So I found an edge case this morning that's probably not as near to the edge as it should be, where the string could look like ` !Goal 45'+4' Richarlison`, and so the regex matches on `!Goal` however it then has an empty capture group. I think I would want to add something like `(!Goal(?:\s\d+'(?:\+\d+\'))*)` but that then causes it to fail if there is more than one timestamp. Edit: Think I figured it out, `!Goal((?:\s\d+'(?:\+\d+')*)*)` appears to work.

Comment: @Eabryt yes, you can use `(!\w+(?:\s\d+'(?:\+\d+')?)*)` - `?` is 0 or 1 quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

If your input always follows the format "bang text blank digits apostrophe blank digits apostrophe etc", then it should be as simple as:

```
!\w+(?:\s\d+')*
```

Explanation:

```
!      matches an exclamation mark
\w+    matches 1 or more word-characters (letters, underscores)
(?:…)  is a non-capturing group
\s     matches a single whitespace character
\d+    matches one or more digits
'      matches the apostrophe character
*      repeatedly matches the group 0 or more times
```

Answer (score 0):

this :

```
(!\w+(?:\s\d+')*)
```

will capture  :

```
"!Goal 27'"
"!Goal 33' 46'"
"!Sub"
```